# How do you change the headlights of a 2001 VW Passat?

Tags: vw, passat, headlight

After popping the hood, it is not immediately obvious how/where the headlights are. How do you get access to them?

Comment: It's not clear to me if you are asking about changing the headlight *bulb* or changing the headlight *housing*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This PDF file seems to have good instructions:

http://adammclane.com/wp-content/uploads/downloads/2011/02/ReplacingHeadlightBulbs.pdf

I haven't tried this myself on a Passat, though the final pieces seem vaguely similar to my New Beetle.

Comment: I also like the instructions here: http://forums.vwvortex.com/showthread.php?3737200-how-to-change-a-headlight-bulb-on-a-2001-passat-HELP!!!

Comment: This tutorial is a dead link, should no longer be accepted.

Comment: @anonymous2 It took me two seconds of Googling to find the same file elsewhere. Please be more helpful next time.

Comment: Great find, @PeterK.  I'll just say that you're better at using google than I.  :)

Comment: :-) Apparently my Google-Fu is strong. Thanks for telling me about the dead link. I've taken a copy of the file and will see about uploading it somewhere more general if it breaks again.

Comment: Passat headlight design changed in the B5 series in the middle of the 2001 MY. The link above applies to changing the headlight bulbs on post-change car; changing the headlight bulbs on the earlier series car is different, as the bulbs and sockets are accessed by removing a large circular rubber seal.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Passat World Forum](http://www.passatworld.com/forums/volkswagen-passat-b5-discussion/84741-headlight-bulb-replacement.html):

> 1. Open hood
> 2. Carefully pull back and remove round weather seals from over the bulb area. These are not attached with anything more than friction and protect the inside bulb and wiring from the weather. Behind this outer cover you will find the bulb, wiring, clips, etc.
> 3. Carefully, but somewhat forcefully, squeeze the sides together and and pull straight back on the black wiring attachement. Mine was a little stuck, but came off with some encouragement. Careful not to pull too far and mess up the wiring. Now you can easily see the bulbs prong connectors and clips that hold the bulb in place.
> 4. After noting the seating of the bulb in the housing (There are three little arms that rest on the light housing and place the light in the correct configuration) squeeze together the silver clips holding the bulb in the housing and gently swing these arms back and away at the same time. This clip is actually one piece. Remove the old bulbs.
> 5. Careful only to touch the silver connectors and not the glass, etc, on the new bulb, place the new bulb in the correct orientation in the housing and reattach silver clips. Now your new bulb is in place and ready to be plugged back in.
> 6. Plug the black wiring harness onto light and replace weather seals.